# Keras model with 2 inputs complains about input shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have been working on a network with 2 inputs to evaluate chess positions for my chess engine.
For this purpose, I converted the network from my C++ code to Keras to be able to train it on the GPU.

My model looks like this:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 20480)        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)            (None, 20480)        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 256)          5243136     input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                 (None, 256)          5243136     input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 512)          0           dense_1[0][0]                    
                                                                 dense_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                 (None, 32)           16416       concatenate_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)                 (None, 32)           1056        dense_3[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)                 (None, 1)            33          dense_4[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 10,503,777
Trainable params: 10,503,777
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Because of the massive input and the huge amount of training data (about 300M positions), I used Sparse matrices during training which worked fine.

I wanted to transfer the weights back to my hand-written c++ code and for debugging purpose, I wanted to feed a single input into the Keras model to compare it to my C++ model.

```
indices =[21768,21769,21770,21771,21773,21774,21775,21788,21825,21830,21890,21893,21952,21959,22019,1288,1289,1290,1291,1292,1293,1294,1295,1345,1350,1410,1413,1472,1479,1539]
eval = -0.24
x_1 = np.zeros(half_input_size)
x_2 = np.zeros(half_input_size)

for i in indices:
    if(i < half_input_size):
        x_1[i] = 1
    else:
        x_2[i-half_input_size] = 1


print(x_1.shape)
print(x_2.shape)

print(model.predict([x_1, x_2]))
```

The shape of both inputs seems to be:

```
(20480,)
(20480,)
```

Yet Keras is giving me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "A:/OneDrive/ProgrammSpeicher/CLionProjects/Koivisto/resources/networkTrainingKeras/Train.py", line 317, in <module>
    print(model.predict([x_1, x_2]))
  File "C:\Users\finne\.conda\envs\DeepLearning\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1441, in predict
    x, _, _ = self._standardize_user_data(x)
  File "C:\Users\finne\.conda\envs\DeepLearning\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 579, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "C:\Users\finne\.conda\envs\DeepLearning\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 145, in standardize_input_data
    str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have a shape (20480,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

I am very happy if someone could briefly tell me what I messed up!

Greetings
Finn

Comment: And yes, during training, I had sparse=True at the input nodes of the model which I changed to sparse=True for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add the batch_dim when you are doing prediction.

if your model accepts 2D inputs, you have to pass 2D samples in prediction

you can simply do it expanding the dimensionality

```
model.predict([np.expand_dims(x_1,0), np.expand_dims(x_2,0)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should a `batch` dimension to your input.

```
x_1 = np.expand_dims(x_1, 0)
x_2 = np.expand_dims(x_1, 0)
```

Now, you have shapes of `(1, 20480)` which means one example with 20480 features